# Set value of drop down select with Materialize.css 1.0.0 without jQuery

Tags: javascript, materialize

In my project, I save the values of the select elements and set them on page load to what the user last selected. This used to work by just setting the `.value = "x"` but now I can't set the values, I can only get them with `instance.getSelectedValues();` as per the Materialize docs?

```
const selectedCategory = document.querySelector('#category');
const materializeSelectedCategory = M.FormSelect.init(selectedCategory);
```

... then on document ready

```
materializeSelectedCategory.value = "SET VALUE"; // This does not work...
```

Can't figure out how to set the values of the Materialize.css drop downs. I use multiple.

**I am NOT using jQuery**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can't figure out how to set the values of the Materialize.css drop downs.
>   materializeSelectedCategory.value = "SET VALUE"; // This does not work...

You need to use **selectedCategory** and dispatch change event:

```
selectedCategory.value = "1";
if (typeof(Event) === 'function') {
    var event = new Event('change');
} else {  // for IE11
    var event = document.createEvent('Event');
    event.initEvent('change', true, true);
}
selectedCategory.dispatchEvent(event);
```

```js
const selectedCategory = document.querySelector('#category');
const materializeSelectedCategory = M.FormSelect.init(selectedCategory);

selectedCategory.value = "1";
if(typeof(Event) === 'function') {
    var event = new Event('change');
}else{
    var event = document.createEvent('Event');
    event.initEvent('change', true, true);
}
selectedCategory.dispatchEvent(event);
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0-beta/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<div class="input-field col s12">
    <select id="category">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <label>Materialize Select</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure if you understood my question fully. I have 3 drop downs. On document ready, I want to set them to what is stored inside localStorage of the browser. Saving the values on each select elements on 'change' eventListener to localStorage works as expected, but when the document is ready I go to pull the values from localStorage and set each drop down respectively which does not work.

Comment: @TaylorA.Leach use your values with **selectedCategory.value** and dispatch the event. Do it for each one. My snippet is only a way to hint you how do achieve the result for one. May it help?

Comment: Hi @gaetanoM, This is working if select element is declared in html code. But it's not working for dynamic select element. After assigning value, I called .formSelect() to initialize. But it's not working

Answer (score 0):

**Reinitializing the component**

An alternative for dispatching a `change` event on the underlying `HTMLSelectElement` is simply reinitializing the component *after* setting the `value`. You have to do that every time the value is changed programmatically as opposed to user interaction (the `init` method is fast, though):

```js
(() => {
  M.AutoInit();

  const start = document.getElementById('start');
  const end = document.getElementById('stop');

  const cat = document.getElementById('category');
  const out = document.getElementById('manual');
  const aut = document.getElementById('auto');
  
  let interval;
  
  document.addEventListener('change', ({ target }) => {
    out.textContent = target.value;
  })
  
  start.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if(interval) return;
  
    interval = setInterval(() => {
      cat.value = (Math.random() * 2).toFixed(0);  
      const inst = M.FormSelect.init(cat);
      aut.textContent = inst.getSelectedValues().join(", ");
    }, 1e3);
  });
      
  end.addEventListener('click', () => {
    interval && clearInterval(interval);
  });
  
})();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<div class="input-field col s12">
    <select id="category">
        <option value="0" disabled selected>Choose your option</option>
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
    <label>Materialize Select</label>
</div>

<p>
  Via value: <span id="manual"></span><br>
  Via getSelectedValues: <span id="auto"></span>
</p>

<button type="button" id="start">Start</button>
<button type="button" id="stop">Stop</button>
```